# Morphia query by referenced object

Tags: mongodb, scala, morphia

I have an object like below

```
class Test1 {

  @Id
  var id: ObjectId = _

  @Reference
  var referrenced: Referrenced = _

  ...
}
```

And referenced object

```
Class Referenced {

  @Id
  var id: ObjectId = _

  var when: Date = _
}
```

How can I find all `Test1` object that has `Referenced` object `when` between times?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$lookup` if you're doing an aggregation MongoDB 3.4.  Otherwise, Mongo's query language doesn't support a join so you'd have to first query for all the ID values for `Referenced` instances between those times and then query for `Test1` instances with those ID values.

Comment: I'm following your seconde solution. Just want to know is there better way. Thanks for your answer.